# Python Library differences between vendors

Tags: python, visual-studio

Simple question: When using pip to install a library in the Python Environment window of Visual Studio  2015 Community I find the import statement then requires an underscore.

Example

**Normal Python distribution:** `import random`

**Community :**                 `import  _random`

I also find `random.randint()` is now not available in the community edition!

Are the Visual Studio pip Python libraries different from the standard distributions from  the Python web site?

Comment: Which version of visual studio? 2015? 2012?

Answer (score 0):

All Python distributions include `random` module and as it is part of the Python standard library. Unless Python is purposely slimmed down e.g. for embedded environments. But in this case it should not be the case.

_random (And all underscore prefixed modules) are native extensions for Python written in C and should not be accessed by the developer directly.

Sounds like Community edition is somehow broken installation.